# How do i access these arrays so that i can multiply inputted values in the diagonal?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

If I inputted 5, it will  generate a square matrix by 5 (5x5)
How do I multiply 1, 7, 13, 19, 25?
[image: How do I multiply 1, 7, 13, 19, 25]

Is there any applicable algorithm for my code so I could multiply the diagonals or do i need to rewrite a new one?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public int e = 0;
    int Row = 0;
    int Column = 0;
    int YAxisPosition = 0; 
    int XAxisPosition = 0;
    int Counter = 0;
    int PositionalValue = 0; 
    TextBox[] MyTextBoxDimA = new TextBox[999999]; 
    TextBox tbRow = new TextBox();
    Button MyButton = new Button();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        AutoScroll = true;
        WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;

        //GENERATING THE SIZE BUTTON
        tbRow = new TextBox();
        tbRow.Text = "5";
        tbRow.Size = new Size(100, 10);
        tbRow.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        Controls.Add(tbRow);

        //GENERATE MATRIX BUTTON
        MyButton = new Button();
        MyButton.Text = "GENERATE MATRIX";
        MyButton.Size = new Size(200, 25);
        MyButton.Click += new EventHandler(MyButton_Click);
        MyButton.Location = new Point(0, 30);
        Controls.Add(MyButton);
    }

    public void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs ee) {
        //CODE FOR GENERATING MATRIX A
        e = 1;
        PositionalValue = 1;
        Counter = 1;

        //POSITION
        YAxisPosition = 60;
        XAxisPosition = 0;
        Row = Convert.ToInt32(tbRow.Text);
        Column = Convert.ToInt32(tbRow.Text);
        while (Row >= e) {
            while (Column >= Counter) {
                MyTextBoxDimA[PositionalValue] = new TextBox(); 
                MyTextBoxDimA[PositionalValue].Location =
                    new Point(XAxisPosition, YAxisPosition); //coordinates (start)
                MyTextBoxDimA[PositionalValue].Size = new Size(70, 10); 
                MyTextBoxDimA[PositionalValue].Text = Convert.ToString(PositionalValue);
                Controls.Add(MyTextBoxDimA[PositionalValue]);
                XAxisPosition = XAxisPosition + 100;
                PositionalValue++;
                Counter++;
            }
            YAxisPosition = YAxisPosition + 50;
            Counter = 1; 
            e++;
            XAxisPosition = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on [databinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can multiply the array that the textboxes are bound to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an algorithm:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 5;
        int ans = 1;
        int current = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            ans = ans * current;
            current += n + 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ans);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop from zero to the size of the matrix.  The index will be used to get each diagonal value (this code assumes that each textbox contains an integer and is not blank):

```
int matrixSize = 5;
int product = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
{
    product *= int.Parse(MyTextBoxDimA[i,i].Text);
}
```